# How to extract the subquery of an update script into a CTE?

Tags: postgresql, update, foreign-key

I store groups and their members in two tables where the member table references the `group_id` as a foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE group_table (
  group_id      INT,
  group_name    VARCHAR(8),
  group_attr1   VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE member_table (
  member_id        INT,
  member_group_id  INT,
  member_name      VARCHAR(4),
  member_attr1     VARCHAR(4),
  member_foo       VARCHAR(4),
  FOREIGN KEY(member_group_id) REFERENCES group_table(group_id)
);
```

Now without knowing (= typing out) any ids I need to update the `member_name`s of one group:

```
INSERT INTO calculator.group_table ("group_id", "group_name", "group_attr1") 
VALUES (0, 'group0', 'group_attr1')

INSERT INTO calculator.member_table ("member_id", "member_group_id", "member_name", "member_attr1") 
VALUES (0, 0, 'alice', 'mgmt'),
       (1, 0, 'bob',   'se1'),
       (2, 0, 'carol', 'se2');
```

Luckily, I can uniquely determine the group by `group_table`s its non-id columns `group_name` and `group_attr1`, and the members by the group and `member_table`s non-id values.

The following works:

```
UPDATE member_table
   SET member_name = 'alice_finnigan'
 WHERE (member_name, member_attr1)  = ('alice', 'mgmt')
   AND member_group_id in (SELECT group_id
                             FROM group_table
                            WHERE group_name  = 'group0' 
                              AND group_attr1 = 'group_attr1');
```

but because I have to use the same subquery many times, I'd like to extract it into a variable and reference it in the UPDATE statement. A CTE seems like a good idea, but I cannot make it work:

```
WITH my_subquery AS (
    SELECT group_id
      FROM group_table
     WHERE group_name  = 'group0' 
       AND group_attr1 = 'group_attr1'
)
UPDATE member_table
   SET member_name = 'alice'
 WHERE (member_name, member_attr1) = ('alice_finnigan', 'mgmt')
   AND member_group_id in my_subquery;
```

gives me a Syntax Error at »my_subquery« (SQLState:  42601)

I'd like to understand what the issue is, and how to do it right. (And how to reuse the CTE for my many UPDATES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTE acts like a table, so you need a proper SELECT to access it:

```
WITH my_subquery AS (
    SELECT group_id
      FROM group_table
     WHERE group_name  = 'group0' 
       AND group_attr1 = 'group_attr1'
)
UPDATE member_table
   SET member_name = 'alice'
 WHERE (member_name, member_attr1) = ('alice_finnigan', 'mgmt')
   AND member_group_id in (select group_id from my_subquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution with CTEs but it worked for my Problem.
I can successfully store the group_id into a new table:

```
SELECT group_table.group_id INTO my_group_id 
  FROM group_table 
 WHERE group_name  = 'group0' 
   AND group_attr1 = 'group_attr1';

 UPDATE calculator.member_table
   SET member_name = 'alice_finnigan'
 WHERE (member_name, member_attr1) = ('alice', 'mgmt')
   AND member_group_id in (SELECT group_id FROM my_group_id);

DROP TABLE my_group_id;
```

However this requires me to know that no table by that name already exists...